# MySQL query optimization (joining similar query results)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In MySQL I wrote the following query. Making it reselect all that data again using `JOIN` does not seem the most effective way to me. How would you rewrite it to make it more efficient?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total' FROM `the_table`
    WHERE `subject_id`=7 ) a
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'unread' FROM `the_table`
    WHERE `subject_id`=7 AND `read`=0 ) b
```

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to get a table with 2 columns: 'total' and 'unread' with a single row having INT values, such as

> total: **200** unread: **20**

Comment: Can you give example input data and output data? It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish with that query.

Comment: Did you actually run this? Without a join column what do you expect to get?

Comment: @JimGarrison of course I've run it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the where clause is the same except for the condition on read you can use SUM/CASE

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total' , 
       SUM(CASE WHEN `read`=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `unread`
 FROM `the_table`
 WHERE `subject_id`=7
```

Comment: +1.  An alternate way would be to use the CASE syntax inside of a COUNT:

    `SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total',
           COUNT(CASE read WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'unread'
    FROM   the_table
    WHERE  subject_id = 7`

Comment: You could also do `SUM(read = 0)` because to MySQL `false = 0` and `true = 1`.